# Disable fill in xml-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, hook, mode, dot-emacs

I'm trying to configure Emacs to not activate Auto-Fill when editing an XML document.

In my `.emacs` file, I add a hook so that text mode will have Auto-Fill on by default:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

I have added a directory to my load path:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
```

Inside that directory, I have written a file `xml.el` for this workstation, and I have tried each of the following in it, to no avail:

```
(add-hook 'xml-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'xml-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)
(remove-hook 'xml-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(remove-hook 'xml-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)
```

How can I disable Auto-Fill in XML mode?

EDIT: It appears this is caused by my `text-mode-hook` mentioned above. How can I override this hook in `nxml-mode`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have written a file `xml.el`"? Did you write your own major mode for editing XML? Does it actually have an `xml-mode-hook`? Normally I would expect to see `nxml-mode` used to edit XML files, which has its own `nxml-mode-hook`.

Comment: No, `xml.el` is in `~/.emacs.d/lisp`.

Comment: Changing my hook calls to use `nxml-mode-hook` did not work either, though.

Comment: Well, it would only work if you were also invoking `nxml-mode`.

Comment: Of course. I restart Emacs every time I change the file.

Comment: `xml.el` is the name of a standard Emacs library. You shouldn't be putting a conflicting filename under your `load-path`, as it may shadow the standard library, breaking anything which depends on it. I recommend using a non-conflicting prefix for all of your custom elisp libraries. I use `my-` as a prefix, for example (for both filenames and function names).

Comment: Recent versions of Emacs use `nxml-mode` by default for XML files. The mode line will tell you, but use `M-:` `major-mode` `RET` if you're not sure.

Comment: Also, `auto-fill-mode` is *not* turned on by default. You need to find *why* it is being turned on in your XML buffers in order to establish how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: By @phils' comment, I discovered Auto-Fill is being activated because of my `text-mode-hook` in my `.emacs` file. How can I override this for XML?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, `nxml-mode` derives from `text-mode`. That's slightly surprising to me (although on closer inspection, it does appear to be standard for markup language modes in Emacs).

In that case you can either *disable* it again in `nxml-mode-hook` (as `text-mode-hook` has already run by that point):

```el
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```

(n.b. you said in the comments that this didn't work for you, but it certainly works for me).

or else just change your `text-mode-hook` code to something like the following, in order to catch this case before auto-fill is enabled:

```el
(defun my-text-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `text-mode'."
  ;; Enable `auto-fill-mode', except in `nxml-mode' (which is derived
  ;; from `text-mode').
  (unless (eq major-mode 'nxml-mode)
    (turn-on-auto-fill)))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-text-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Adding the first snippet to my `.emacs` works, so it appears that the real problem is that my elisp file in the load path is not being run.

Comment: How are you loading it?

Comment: I have a file `my-xml.el` in `~/.emacs.d/lisp`, which is in my `load-path` list.

Comment: If that's all, then you're *not* loading it. The `load-path` tells Emacs where to look for libraries when asked to load one, but Emacs won't load anything without being told to. You need to call `(load "my-xml")` or, if your file includes `(provide 'my-xml)`, you could use `(require 'my-xml)`.